# Is there any dictionary on Ubuntu that comes with built in pronunciation?

Tags: dictionary

I am in badly need of a good off-line dictionary that has pronunciation support. I mean I can hear the pronunciation of the word I search with it's meaning and others. Is there any for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Goldendict](http://goldendict.org/download.php) is the most customizable dictionary on Ubuntu. It supports audio output for pronunciations, but you will have to supply it with a dictionary that includes these audio samples. I don't know of any free ones that have this functionality and I don't have enough free time on my hands to search for one right now).

You might find some more information on the [GoldenDict forums](http://goldendict.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1792).